# GRUB Multiboot and Kernel Updates

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kernel

A couple of days ago, I installed Xubuntu 14.04 alongside my Ubuntu 14.04 system.  I had to do a little work to get Ubuntu 14.04 to be the default system, but that's resolved now.  The thing is, if I remember correctly, Ubuntu-type systems run 'update-grub' upon installing a kernel update.  Does this mean that, since the Ubuntu partition's Grub is "in control", I'll have to run 'update-grub' from Ubuntu whenever Xubuntu gets an updated kernel (as I suspect).  If I must, I must, it's no problem; I just want to be sure.

Thanks manymuch